# How to declare Dictionary of Dictionary in java

Tags: java, dictionary

I have C#.Net code which calling a SOAP Service created in JAVA Ecllips kepler. A API(function) exposed from web service should take a data from C#.NET code as parameter. Data which i needs to send to API is of dictionary of dictionary in c#.NET as follows:

`Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> LinksCollection = null`;

How this structure can be implemented in Java ?

What I search & try:

## 1]Following are way to implement dictionary in java:

```
1]HashMap

    eg:Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

2]LinkedHashMap
3]Hashtable  

     eg: Dictionary d = new Hashtable();

Is it the right way to implement as follows ?   

 

    Declaring Dictionary: 
       Map<String, String> mapA = new HashMap<String, String>();
     Declaring Dictionary of Dictionary:  
       Map<String, mapA> map = new HashMap<String, mapA>();
```

Comment: `Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>()` would be a better place to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like in C# except with the word HashMap rather than Dictionary

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>
```

> ```
> Map<String, String> mapA = new HashMap<String, String>();
> Map<String, mapA> map = new HashMap<String, mapA>();
> ```

No, because mapA is an *instance*, not a *type*. That wouldn't work in C# either

```
//no
var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var e = new Dictionary<string, d>(); //error: `d` is a variable, but is used like a type
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Cauis Jard's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67102848/139985), there is no single "best" type to use in all situations.

- If you don't care about ordering, then `HashMap` is the most obvious choice.  This could be your "default" choice ... if thread safety is not an issue.
- If you want to preserve insertion order, use `LinkedHashMap`.
- If you want to iterate the dictionary keys in a sorted order, use `TreeMap`.
- If you want to use the dictionary from multiple threads, select from the following depending on your requirements:

  - `ConcurrentHashMap`
  - `SkipListMap`
  - `Collections.synchronizedMap(...)`
  - `Collections.unmodifiableMap(...)`

You could also use `Properties` or even the legacy / obsolete `Hashtable` or `Dictionary` classes.